# How is this CSS snippet drawing an arrow?

Tags: css

While following this [tutorial](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/11/how-to-create-a-simple-css3-tooltip/), this piece of code is claimed to draw an arrow, but was never explained properly.

```css
.tooltip:hover:before{
    border: solid;
    border-color: #333 transparent;
    border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
    bottom: 20px;
    content: "";
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">Sample text</div>
```

Can anybody please explain how's it doing that?

Comment: Cause you are only supplying 3 out of 4 sides of the border.. not sure how that technically works though.

Comment: google "css arrow" ... the first thing that comes up ... https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Comment: @putvande check my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is in the border color and width. Imagine a box with zero height and width, just the borders, those borders are meeting in the exact center. If you draw one border with a color (#333 in this case) and leave the rest as transparent, you get an arrow.

The technique is explained further on CSS Tricks: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/#article-header-id-2

Comment: I got the technique from the link. Many thanks! But why it was needed to use `before` and `after` pseudo-elements?

Comment: @Holmes.Sherlock because it creates a pseudo-element to draw the border inside it. It's equivalent to having a div/span next to your element and use it to draw the border. The only different is that this method uncluttered the DOM.